# Failure when running CockroachDB Helm Chart on Minikube: "Creating data directory: mkdir /cockroach/cockroach-data/auxiliary: permission denied"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube, cockroachdb

When I try to run the cockroachdb on minikube v1.29.0 on Fedora 37 (selinux disabled) with default parameters, 2 of 3 nodes fails with the following error:

```bash
Creating data directory: mkdir /cockroach/cockroach-data/auxiliary: permission denied
```

I don't know if it's more related to cockroachdb, minikube or my linux system.
But if you have some information or hints, I'm all ears.

Thank you !!

**Steps to reproduce**

```bash
minikube start --cpus=2 --memory=2g --nodes=3

helm repo add cockroachdb https://charts.cockroachdb.com/
helm repo update

helm upgrade --install cockroachdb cockroachdb/cockroachdb
```

**Results**

```bash
$ kubectl get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS     AGE
pod/cockroachdb-0            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1 (8s ago)   26s
pod/cockroachdb-1            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1 (2s ago)   26s
pod/cockroachdb-2            0/1     Running            0            26s
pod/cockroachdb-init-gkb2z   1/1     Running            0            26s

NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE
service/cockroachdb          ClusterIP   None            <none>        26257/TCP,8080/TCP   26s
service/cockroachdb-public   ClusterIP   10.100.59.219   <none>        26257/TCP,8080/TCP   26s
service/kubernetes           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP              6m34s

NAME                           READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/cockroachdb   0/3     26s

NAME                                                  SCHEDULE       SUSPEND   ACTIVE   LAST SCHEDULE   AGE
cronjob.batch/cockroachdb-rotate-self-signer          0 0 1 */11 *   False     0        <none>          26s
cronjob.batch/cockroachdb-rotate-self-signer-client   0 0 */26 * *   False     0        <none>          26s

NAME                         COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/cockroachdb-init   0/1           26s        26s
```

```bash
$ kubectl get po -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE   IP           NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cockroachdb-0            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2 (15s ago)   52s   10.244.2.2   minikube-m03   <none>           <none>
cockroachdb-1            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2 (11s ago)   52s   10.244.1.4   minikube-m02   <none>           <none>
cockroachdb-2            0/1     Running            0             52s   10.244.0.3   minikube       <none>           <none>
cockroachdb-init-gkb2z   1/1     Running            0             52s   10.244.1.3   minikube-m02   <none>           <none>
```

```bash
$ kubectl logs cockroachdb-0
Defaulted container "db" out of: db, copy-certs (init)
++ hostname
+ exec /cockroach/cockroach start --join=cockroachdb-0.cockroachdb.datastore.svc.cluster.local:26257,cockroachdb-1.cockroachdb.datastore.svc.cluster.local:26257,cockroachdb-2.cockroachdb.datastore.svc.cluster.local:26257 --advertise-host=cockroachdb-0.cockroachdb.datastore.svc.cluster.local --certs-dir=/cockroach/cockroach-certs/ --http-port=8080 --port=26257 --cache=25% --max-sql-memory=25% --logtostderr=INFO
Flag --logtostderr has been deprecated, use --log instead to specify 'sinks: {stderr: {filter: ...}}'.
E230321 11:03:10.501705 1 1@cli/clierror/check.go:35  [-] 1  ERROR: connection lost.
E230321 11:03:10.501705 1 1@cli/clierror/check.go:35  [-] 1 +creating data directory: mkdir /cockroach/cockroach-data/auxiliary: permission denied
ERROR: connection lost.

creating data directory: mkdir /cockroach/cockroach-data/auxiliary: permission denied
Failed running "start"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking ChatGPT about this, he pointed that the SecurityContext feature could be an issue: `securityContext` should be disabled in `values.yml` in the Helm chart as it prevents the writing of these files.

I still have a lot to learn about Kube though.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm disabling security context from the statefulsets in values.yaml according to your answer and the documentation, but the problem is the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and i managed to solve it by using a values.yaml file with the following configs:

```
statefulSet:
  securityContext:
    enabled: false
```

Then installing the cockroachdb helm chart with:

```
helm install {Custom name} --values values.yaml cockroachdb/cockroachdb
```

Refer to the official documentation for more detailed info:

```
https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/deploy-cockroachdb-with-kubernetes?filters=helm
```

If the problem persists, it's probably a folder permission issue with the statefulSets. Use chmod to fix.

Regards.